# I'm looking for a SIP client software stack

Tags: sip, python-sip

I'm looking for a SIP client software stack.  It will need to be able to send audio files and collect Telephone-events.  It is critically important that it supports connections through proxy-servers (Session Border Controllers).  There is no need for compression Codecs (PCMU is fine)

Python would be my preferred language, but I'm flexible.  Open Source is always good, but I'm not averse to paying licensing fees

Suggestions are most appreciated